# Angularjs: How to read scope rendered value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Im working on an angularjs project. And really want to know how can I access values that rendered by scope by jquery ( or other javascript codes). Here is a part of my template:

```
<div class="bars" data-label="Population" data-val="{{town.population}}" data-color="#cccccc">
```

So, Im going to use the value of the attribute of `data-val` which is rendered by scope. I'm doing it like this:

```
TownApp.directive('bars', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         // I tried : this will get value: {{town.population}} as a string itself.
         $(".bar").jqbar({value: $(this).data('val');
         // also tried: this will get undefined
         elem.jqbar({ value: attrs.val});
         // and so on......
    }
  }
}
```

})

As I described in the comments, seems while the directive is running, the scope value is still not rendered to page, so that the further codes can not read the value properly.

So, my questions is how can I do this? Thanks a lot !

UPDATE:

Adding controller and factory codes:

```
var TownApp=angular.module('TownApp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);

TownApp.factory('Town', function($http) {
    return $http.get('/database.json').then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    })
});

var TownCtrl = TownApp.controller('TownCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, Town,   $location){
  Town.then(function(response){ 
  $scope.towns = response;

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
     if(response[i].Code === $routeParams.townId){
        var currentTown = response[i];
    }
      $scope.town = currentTown;
  }

  //.......
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `data-val="{{town.population}}"` to `data-val="town.population"`, we can get it directly from that.

Then we'll want to use `scope.$eval` in the directive:

```
TownApp.directive('bars', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        // evaluate attribute contents
        elem.jqbar({ value: scope.$eval(attrs.val) });
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to update the population value and have the bar change in real time (if jqbar supports that, I'm not sure):

```
TownApp.directive('bars', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.jqbar({ /* whatever options you want */ });
        scope.$watch(attrs.val, function(val) {
            // I'm not sure of the exact call the update the widget,
            // but it's probably something like this
            elem.jqbar('option', 'value', val);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

There's also a third way, by using an isolate scope, but this can cause problems if you have other directives on the same element:

```
TownApp.directive('bars', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    // Make a new isolate scope
    scope: { val: '=' },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.jqbar({ value: scope.val });
        // If you want to $watch this value for changes,
        // use scope.$watch('val', function() {...})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, cool! thanks a lot. I'll play with it little by little. Thanks again.

Comment: oops, hi Jussi, i tried all above, but all of them returnning `undefined`. Instead of values. Any idea?

Comment: And you're sure town.population has something valid in it? Here's a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/aD7dX/

NOTE: I had a typo in the second one, it's $watch instead of $wach

Comment: While i use `ng-repeat` to display the `key` `value` part of `$scope.town`, it all works good. So, I guess there are valid values.

Comment: I find an interesting thing is, if I `console.log(scope)` inside the directive, I can see `town` attribute there, but if I try `console.log(scope.town)` then I'll get `undefined`. So weird.

Comment: Ah, if you're loading the data asynchronously then it's probably not ready when the directive is linked, so you'll need to put the logic into a $watch, like in the second block. The console.log thing supports this. Chrome (and probably FF) evaluate the contents of larger objects like the scope fully only when it's opened, so it's not there when you log it, but it's there when you open it.

Comment: A new fiddle which uses the $watch mechanic: http://jsfiddle.net/aD7dX/2/

If jqbar doesn't like changing its value after initialising, you might have to destroy the widget and recreate it each time in the $watch.

Comment: I just changed async JSON data to static JSON data, seems the first method is working perfect. I'll keep working with this version. And ill definitely check out the `$watch` method later. Thanks very much!